# How to draw Arabic Text on Android after reading from a file?

Tags: android, file, arabic

I've figured out how to draw Arabic characters properly (connected and right to left) using string literals like this:

```
textView.setTypeFace(Typeface.createFromAssets(getAssets(),"DejaVuSans.ttf"));
textView.setText("\uFEB3\uFE92\uFE98\uFE94");
```

But for some reason I cannot get the arabic to format properly if I read anything from a file using InputStreams like this:

arabictext.txt:

```
سبتة
```

and the code:

```
InputStream istream = as.open("arabictext.txt");

     String string;
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(istream);

        /* Read bytes to the Buffer until
         * there is nothing more to read(-1). */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                baf.append((byte)current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        string = new String(baf.toByteArray(), 0, baf.length(), "UTF-8");
```

and then displaying the string in a textview. The letters are ordered correctly but are not connected nor are they in the proper form for end of word/middle of word. This makes no sense to me because I thought that each form of each letter is a different Unicode code point.

2) Putting the actual code values in the file just causes the textview to display the code point values as a string.

Any help would be appreciated! I started to make a custom view to just draw the text, but it got complicated, fast.

Comment: You can find your solution [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408). Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

salam Alaikom,
Actually there is a difference between the text you use in direct code:

```
textView.setText("\uFEB3\uFE92\uFE98\uFE94");
```

And what you got from File which I suppose will be :

```
\u0633\u0628\u062a\u0647
```

so try to insert characters in final format ( after rendering ) in file then you will get expected result.

Comment: I actually ended up using Amr Gawash's Arabic Reshaper. Thanks for the help though.